# WEBVTT into HLS does not work anymore on last iOS version

Tags: video, safari, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, webvtt

I've some issue to reproduce WEBVTT that are inside an HLS on videos over last version of iOS and MacOS (on physical device and safari)

My webVTT are composed in this way:

```
WEBVTT
TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:140000,LOCAL:00:00:00.000

00:00:36.667--> 00:00:37.583 
Hello

00:00:38.750--> 00:00:39.417 
Hey

00:00:40.667--> 00:00:41.792 
Thanks
```

Already tried to remove the string "TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:140000,LOCAL:00:00:00.000" but does not solve the situation

The main playlist is composed as follow:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,NAME="ENG",LANGUAGE="ENG",URI="link-to-caption/ENG"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,NAME="POR",LANGUAGE="POR",URI="link-to-caption/POR"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,NAME="ESP",LANGUAGE="ESP",URI="link-to-caption/ESP"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,NAME="ITA",LANGUAGE="ITA",URI="link-to-caption/ITA"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=688000,SUBTITLES="subs",RESOLUTION=640x360
link-variant1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=1400000,RESOLUTION=842x480
link-variant2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=2800000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
link-variant3
```

On older versions of iOS captions are working fine.